# How to migrate angular-fullstack app to a domain with a base URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, yeoman-generator-angular

I have a fairly complicated issue in that I originally developed a MEAN app with the Yeoman fullstack-angular generator with no base URL. In development http://localhost:9000/ worked just fine.

Moving into production, I'm using a reverse Apache proxy with a particular path example.com/foo to serve http://localhost:9000. Now when I load up example.com/foo I get a bunch of 404 errors (of course) because eg example.com/app, example.com/bower_components don't exist.

I'm a little out of my league here and no where to start, is there some Express/Angular/etc config variables I should be looking at to help with this migration?

server/config/express.js yielded no hints and I can't find anything in the Grunt file to make wiredep compile the correct links. Or maybe there is even a way to do this in Apache...

Comment: What I have in the Apache file is: ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:9000/ ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:9000/ and it's serving the App all the files aren't serving relative to /foo

Comment: I think the proxypassreverse has to have "proxypassreverse  /   http:// example.com/foo"

Comment: Another way to test is putting it on github pages.  How? Create a free github account then create a repository named (username).github.io that will also be the url to your website.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, the issue was that I need to deploy a MEAN app behind a base URL /foo. Do that I:

1) Used the following Apache rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ http://localhost:9000/$1 [P]
```

2) Now we just need to just make all requests go to example.com/foo/whatever. Edit the base tag in index.html to be:

```
<base href="/foo/" />
```

3) Made all hrefs and service calls relative instead of absolute (Angular providers works with the `<base>` tag)

Comment: How do you do step 3 ?

Comment: This was a long time ago, but I think you'd just need to remove the opening `/` from the beginning of URLs in any links or AJAX calls. `<a href="/my/url">` -> `<a href="my/url">`. Links are relative to what you set in step 2

Comment: Thanks. Actualy, it seems to work by doing like this `<a href="./my/url">` with a dot. Can you confirm me if it's the same as doing like `<a href="my/url">`